# React map over two array and show result in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays:

```
this.state = {
  array1: [{id: 1, name: 'test1'}, {id: 2, name: 'test2'}],
  array2: [{testId: 1, color: 'red'}, {testId: 1, color: 'blue'}, {testId:2, color: 'green'}]
}
```

How can I map over two array and set data in table like this:

```
test1 red blue
test2 green
```

`testId` of second array is same id of first array.

Comment: iterate over array1, grab the name, then filter array2 based on the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all the elements in `array2` that have the same `testId` as an element's `id` in `array1` and just render those.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    array1: [{ id: 1, name: "test1" }, { id: 2, name: "test2" }],
    array2: [
      { testId: 1, color: "red" },
      { testId: 1, color: "blue" },
      { testId: 2, color: "green" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { array1, array2 } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {array1.map(el => {
          const colors = array2.filter(e => e.testId === el.id);

          return (
            <div key={el.id}>
              <span>{el.name}</span>
              {colors.map((c, i) => (
                <span key={i}> {c.color} </span>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```